# How do I upgrade to Play Billing Library version 5.0 using Flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, in-app-purchase

I tried to migrate my apps to Billing version 5.0.0 It works for some of my apps except one, which crashes with the following error. If I revert to Billing version 3.0.2, then it works.

```
E/AndroidRuntime( 9885): java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method setReplaceSkusProrationMode(I)Lcom/android/billingclient/api/BillingFlowParams$Builder; in class Lcom/android/billingclient/api/BillingFlowParams$Builder; or its super classes (declaration of 'com.android.billingclient.api.BillingFlowParams$Builder' appears in /data/app/~~T2Kh46nWychg2xWUZiO5EA==/com.blueedgez.paintover-IPoCtqgP0Ez5df07rfzPyw==/base.apk!classes2.dex)
E/AndroidRuntime( 9885):        at io.flutter.plugins.inapppurchase.MethodCallHandlerImpl.launchBillingFlow(MethodCallHandlerImpl.java
```

Comment: What is your package version? Please also add your `flutter doctor` to better understand your flutter and dart versions.

Comment: You have to wait for the new version of `in_app_purchase` because the current version is using `Google Play Billing Library 3.0` and the new minimum required is `4.0`, [Github](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/107370)

Comment: Is the error occuring in release mode of app or also on debug mode?

Comment: The issue still persist please thorough check the answer you may have not migrated your billing library correctly to 5.0.0.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/73890771/10147641

Answer (score 5):

Have you tried to clean or upgrade the Flutter version. As it looks like your Flutter SDK still holds `in_app_purchase_android-0.2.2+1 or lower version`.
Because upgrading `in_app_purchase: ^3.0.7` will have `in_app_purchase_android-0.2.3+4` using implementation `'com.android.billingclient:billing:5.0.0'`

Answer (score 0):

Try to upgrade your `in_app_purchase` version to `+3.0.6` and above.

Seems that older versions raise irrelevant deprecation warnings. Issue solved in `3.0.6` release.

Check out the [official changelog](https://pub.dev/packages/in_app_purchase/changelog):

[image]

Comment: In my new app, I use version 3.0.7 and I also add the following in AndroidManifest.xml. I don't know how to validate if the warning is fixed. 
`<meta-data
    android: name="com.google.android.play.billingclient.version"
    android: value="4.0.0" />`

Answer (score 0):

An possible answer will find in following [link](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/deprecation-faq)

From their docs you must add `com.android.vending.BILLING permission`.

Make sure your `AndroidManifest.xml` contains an entry with name `com.google.android.play.billingclient.version`. If the entry isn't present, check your manifest merge settings to see if the manifest attribute is being dropped during manifest merging.

This deprecation prevents only `new apps` and `updates` from using older versions of the `Play Billing Library`